# How to fix an error with maven plugin and java version when deploying project on heroku?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, heroku

I've been trying to deploy Spring Boot project on heroku using git hub repository, but I keep getting an error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project charity: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 12 -> [Help 1]

I've tried creating system.properties, as adviced on Heroku:

java.runtime.version=12
maven.version=3.7.0

and adding heroku plugins to pom.xml.

I am copying the pom.xml file below:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>pl.coderslab</groupId>
<artifactId>charity</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>charity</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>12</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId><artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version></dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId><artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version></dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId><artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version></dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId><artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version></dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is maven.version `3.7.0` supported? It's not part of this [`list`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support), see  `Specifying a Maven version`.

Comment: You should use either most recent version of Spring Boot (2.2.0.RELEASE) or 2.1.8.RELEASE at least or you have to overwrite the maven-compiler-plugin version to use 3.8.1 furthermore it looks like you are not really using JDK 12 to compile your project....

Comment: the system.properties file is without extension like txt or something right?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `system.properties` file to look exactly like this:

```
java.runtime.version=12
```

Then make sure it's committed to Git and pushed to Github using `git ls-files`.

You don't need to the `maven.version`, and if you want to control your maven version you should use the [Maven Wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper).